# Check for spaces and replace with zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a tab delimited file with 'n' no. of fields and doing some computation for each row and printing it to the console. The problem I am facing is some of the attributes in some rows do not have a value and has empty string. I would like to identify such empty strings and replace them with zeroes. Here is my code and sample input as below.

Code :-

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
with open('input1.txt') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile,delimiter='\t')
    inputm = list(reader) #contents of csv   

for i in inputm[1:]:
    print('\n',str(datetime.strptime(i[0].split(':')[1], '%Y%m%d'))[:10] ,i[1],sum(map(float,i[2:6]))/4,i[6])
```

Input :-

```
1:20150501  123 10  20  0   0   'xyz'
2:20150501  124 0   20.6    90  18.7    'abc'
3:20150501:replacement  123 10.9    20.3    0   80  'def'
4:20150501  134 10  20  50.6    0   'ghi'
5:20150501  126 10.7    26.8    0   0   'jkl'
6:20150501  123 8.9 20  0   'mno'
```

Comments :- 6th row has a space in 5th field. Such fields need to be identified and replace with zero.

Comment: I would like to check if its an empty string or not before mapping the data to float... Its there in my print statement...

Comment: What's preventing you from doing the check?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a list comprehension that allows you to do if/else conditions. As a test

```
>>> i = ['11', '', '3.3', '']
>>> sum(float(v) if v else 0.0 for v in i)
14.3
```

Putting it into your code you get

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
with open('input1.txt') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile,delimiter='\t')
    inputm = list(reader) #contents of csv   

for i in inputm[1:]:
    print('\n', str(datetime.strptime(i[0].split(':')[1], '%Y%m%d'))[:10],
        i[1], sum(float(v) if v else 0.0 for v in i[2:6])/4,i[6])
```

**Update**

It can be hard to present examples with tabs because stackoverflow filters them out. One technique is to write a bit of code that writes bytes to a test file so others can run that. Here is a working example showing how the `csv` module recognizes that that there is an empty tab-delimited cell in the last line and replaces it with an empty string. And the conversions work!

```
# write a test file we can work with
open('mytest.csv', 'wb').write(
b"""1:20150501\t123\t10\t20\t0\t0\t'xyz'
2:20150501\t124\t0\t20.6\t90\t18.7\t'abc'
3:20150501:replacement\t123\t10.9\t20.3\t0\t80\t'def'
4:20150501\t134\t10\t20\t50.6\t0\t'ghi'
5:20150501\t126\t10.7\t26.8\t0\t0\t'jkl'
6:20150501\t123\t8.9\t20\t0\t\t'mno'""")

import csv

with open('mytest.csv', newline='') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter='\t', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        converted = [float(v) if v else 0.0 for v in row[1:5]]
        print(row, converted)
```

Output:

```
['1:20150501', '123', '10', '20', '0', '0', "'xyz'"] [123.0, 10.0, 20.0, 0.0]
['2:20150501', '124', '0', '20.6', '90', '18.7', "'abc'"] [124.0, 0.0, 20.6, 90.0]
['3:20150501:replacement', '123', '10.9', '20.3', '0', '80', "'def'"] [123.0, 10.9, 20.3, 0.0]
['4:20150501', '134', '10', '20', '50.6', '0', "'ghi'"] [134.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.6]
['5:20150501', '126', '10.7', '26.8', '0', '0', "'jkl'"] [126.0, 10.7, 26.8, 0.0]
['6:20150501', '123', '8.9', '20', '0', '', "'mno'"] [123.0, 8.9, 20.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: This makes sense. But would the `i` value in your fist example really see empty elements like that? I would think it would see a space and just go to the next element in the line. For example(starting at index 2), line 6 would see `i = ['8.9', '20' '0', 'mno']` as opposed to `i = ['8.9', '20', '0', ' ', 'mno']`

Comment: @TMartin Stackoverflow's code blocks remove tabs to its kinda hard to see, but if it is a properly implemented tab-delimited file, the row would read as `['8.9', '20', '0', ' ', 'mno']`. I'll cook up an example and add it here.

Comment: @TMartin - I've updated to show that `csv.reader` adds an empty string placeholder into the row.

Comment: Brilliant, it makes much more sense knowing its correctly tab delimited. I didn't realize SO overwrote them. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a loop and a conditional?

```
for idx, val in enumerate(i)
  if i[idx].isspace():
    i[idx] = 0
```

This would go inside your 'line' loop

```
for i in inputm[1:]:
  for idx, val in enumerate(i)
    if i[idx].isspace():
      i[idx] = 0
  print('\n',str(datetime.strptime(i[0].split(':')[1], '%Y%m%d'))[:10] ,i[1],sum(map(float,i[2:6]))/4,i[6])
```

Comment: Edited my answer